# What can I do about qadha for a Ramadan from over a year ago?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

Brothers and sisters, I am 14 years old, and about two years ago, I hit puberty, and unfortunately started masturbating. And all of Ramadan I masturbated and broke most of my fasts.at that point of my life,
I didn’t really care for religion, and I didn’t even consider making them up. Is it permissible for me to make them up NOW, 2 Ramadans later?

Comment: Yes, think of it like a debt or money you owe. Regardless how much time passes, the debt is always with you until you repay.

Answer (score 1):

It is obligatory on you to fullfill your missed fasts and breaking your fasts both of them if you are able to do so

It is narrated in Muwatta Malik that Yahya related to me from Malik from Abd ar-Rahman ibn al-Qasim that his father used to say,

"If someone has to make up for days not fasted in Ramadan and does not do them before the next Ramadan comes although he is strong enough to do so, he should feed a poor man with a mudd of wheat for every day that he has missed, and he has to fast the days he owes as well."

if a person is fasting and he intentionally breaks his fast (without any valid reason) by eating, drinking or engaging in sexual intercourse intentionally then not only will it be compulsory for him to do qada of that fast, it will also be compulsory for him to observe kaffara. The kaffara for intentionally breaking the fast in Ramadan is to fast for two consecutive months. This is if he starts on the first day of a lunar month. Otherwise (if he doesn’t start on the first day of a lunar month), he must fast for 60 consecutive days. In this duration (of 2 months or 60 days), the days when it is prohibited to fast (i.e. the 2 Eid days and 3 days of Ayyam al-Tashreeq) must not come. If a person does not have the strength to fast for two consecutive months then he must feed 60 poor people with two meals (or alternatively he can give each one of them the value of sadaqa al-fitr).

It is better if you could ask any Mufti or talk to your Imam of mosque directly 
so he could guide you if you are not mature enough to understand this.